# MATLAB: Resolve inf outcome

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to compute the following. The problem is that I get inf for the third item that is being computed. How can I resolve that so that there is no inf-value any longer?

```
num_labels = 2;
htheta = [0.2 0.5; 0.8 0.1; 0.6 1; 0.7 0.4]
y =      [1;  0;   0;  1;]
m = 4;


wes = ones(m, num_labels);
J = 0;


for k = 1:num_labels
        for r = 1:m
        if (htheta(r, k) < 0.5) && y(r, 1) ~= 0
            wes(r, k) = 2;
        else if (htheta(r, k) > 0.5) && y(r, 1) ~= 1
                wes(r, k) = 4;
            else wes(r, k) = 1;
            end
        end
    end
    yk = y == k;
    hthetak = htheta(:, k);
    Jk1 = (-yk .* log(hthetak) - (1 - yk) .* log(1 - hthetak));
    Jk2 = (-yk .* log(hthetak) - (1 - yk) .* log(1 - hthetak)) .* wes(:, k);
    Jk3 = 1 / m * sum( (-yk .* log(hthetak) - (1 - yk) .* log(1 - hthetak)) .* wes(:, k) );
    J = J + Jk3;
end

Jk1
Jk2
Jk3
J
```

Comment: Good thing you had your answer and your problem solved, but please leave some information for the other people who will have similar problems. In your last edit you removed all your (_faulty_) code, so now nobody can have a clue about what the answer is about. Don't be shy to leave your code in your question, even if there are a few flaws, that is how the knowledge can be passed on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`htheta` is equal to 1 in one of its pairs of indices `(3,2)`.

`Jk3` is computed using a value of `log(1 - hthetak)`, which is undefined for `hthetak == 1`.
At the same time, `yk` has a value of zero, since `k=2`, and `y` is never equal to 2.

This makes the product `-Inf`, and you're subtracting this, hence you get `Inf`.

This MathWorks page about [Infinity and NaN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/infinity-and-nan.html) might be helpful.

Comment: I take it from your edit and comment that this isn't the code you're actually running? Is this a function you're passing values of htheta to, and the ones in the question were just examples you picked?